# MySQL select command with a column named "set"

Tags: mysql

I would like to select some parameters in a column of my database. The issue that I have is that the column where I want to select the data is named "set".

```
SELECT * FROM database.table where set=5130;
```

"Set" is also a keyword in MySQL which leads to an error :

```
Error Code: 1064. You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'set=5130' at line 1
```

How should I bypass this issue ?

Comment: Maybe this question about quoting helps https://stackoverflow.com/q/11321491/1741542. Basically use backticks around `set`.

Comment: Bypass it by not using any keywords as column names. It's just a pain.

Comment: Thank you for your reply ! Sadly I can't change the column name, I didn't create the database, I'm working on it. I'll use backsticks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I guess changing the column name is not an option for you. Then you need to use backticks (`).

```
SELECT * FROM database.table where `set`=5130;
```

Answer (score 0):

The best approach would probably be to rename the column. If this is not an option, you can escape it by surrounding it with backticks:

```sql
SELECT * FROM database.table WHERE `set` = 5130;
-- Here ---------------------------^---^
```

Comment: I can't change the column name, I didn't create the database. Anyway thanks for the reply !